# How do you install a .NET 5 WPF Application?

Tags: wpf, .net-core, wix

I moved a WPF application to .NET 5.0 and I'm completely stuck on how to install and deploy it to customers.

I can create a WIX installer easily enough. But if .NET 5.0 isn't installed on the target computer the application simply fails to launch. In some instances it reports that .NET is missing (without specifying a version).

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way in Wix of telling if .NET 5 is installed on a machine. In fact, there doesn't even seem to be a way of telling in C# if .NET is installed so I can't even build a reliable bootstrapper.

Am I missing something obvious? Surely somebody at Microsoft must have thought through how install would work in this configuration?

Edit: .NETCore5 -> .NET5. The self-contained executable is a great solution. Somehow hadn't heard of this before. It's a bit of a beast size-wise, but disk space is cheap these days.

Comment: There is no .NET Core 5, just .NET 5. And nothing prevents you from creating a self contained executable, which includes .NET runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish a .NET Core (and .NET 5) app as a self-contained app that contains all components of the app, including the .NET libraries and target runtime. This means that the users aren't required to download and install .NET on their machines when running the app.

Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) for more information about the *self-contained*  and *framework-dependent* publishing modes that are supported in .NET Core/5.